# Python pandas dataframe group by based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, conditional-statements, dataframe

My question is simple, I have a dataframe and I `groupby` the results based on a column and get the size like this:

```
df.groupby('column').size()
```

Now the problem is that I only want the ones where size is greater than *X*. I am wondering if I can do it using a lambda function or anything similar? I have already tried this:

```
df.groupby('column').size() > X
```

and it prints out some True and False values.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The grouped result is a regular DataFrame, so just filter the results as usual:

```
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
 after = df.groupby('a').size()
 >> after
 a
 a    3
 b    2
 c    1
 d    1
 dtype: int64

 >> after[after > 2]
 a
 a    3
 dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 30):

Try this code:

```
df.groupby('column').filter(lambda group: group.size > X)
```

Answer (score 0):

### In Pandas > 2.0

and as per [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) you can use the function `count()` to achieve this.

See below:

```
df.groupby("group_col")\
  .filter(lambda x: x['another_col'].count() > X)\
  .groupby("group_col").size()
```

You can also emit the last `groupby` to get only those rows that have count greater than `X`